# Passing arguments to a spawned process does not work in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, embedded

I need to pass two addresses (32 bit) to a process spawned by the execl command from C as follows. In the first program:

```
  char buffer[18];
  sprintf (&buffer[0],"%x\0 %x\0",lock, count);
  arg_list[0]=&(buffer[0]);
  arg_list[1]=&(buffer[10]);
  execl ("/somedirectory/second_process", arg_list[0], arg_list[1], NULL);
```

Then in my second program I try and parse the addresses as follows:

```
  if (argc != 2) {
      printf ("PROCESS 2: Invalid number of arguments. Terminating %i\n", argc);
      return -1;
  }

 if ( !(sscanf (argv[1],"%x",&lock)) || !(sscanf (argv[2],"%x",&count)) ) {
      printf ("PROCESS 2: Problem with parameters passed in");
      return -1;
```

But my program keeps on giving an error saying that the parameters passed in are invalid. When I try and print out the recieved arguments, my program hangs.

```
 printf ("The arguments passsed in are %s %s", argv[1], argv[2]);
```

FIXED:

I was making the execl call incorrectly. It should have been:

```
  execl ("/somedirectory/second_process", "second_process" arg_list[0], arg_list[1], NULL);
```

Also in process 2:

```
  if (argc != 3) {
      printf ("PROCESS 2: Invalid number of arguments. Terminating %i\n", argc);
      return -1;
  }
```

As the first argument passed in is supposed to be that of the process name as Chris below suggested.

Thanks!

Comment: "process spawned by the excel command" - Excel? So is this Visual Basic? (Just kidding.)

Comment: You should probably use `%08x`, which you seem to assume.  But if count expands to an 8 digit hex value, then you are writing 19 bytes to a buffer that isn't big enough to hold them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are ALWAYS 0 based in C, so your two arguments will be `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`, and `argv[2]` will be a null pointer, so the sscanf will fail, crash, or hang.

Now *normally* you should always pass the program name as the first (`argv[0]`) argument.  So you want:

```
execl ("/somedirectory/second_process", "second_process", arg_list[0], arg_list[1], NULL);
```

that is, you should actually pass THREE arguments (so `argc == 3` in the second program).

Answer (score 1):

In your case `argc` will be three.  The name of the executing file is always the first argument.

Comment: setting it to 2 yields an error:

PROCESS 2: Invalid number of arguments. Terminating 2

Comment: @Falcata that's why shf301 said you need to check for 3 :)

Comment: This is false.  Exec calls let you specify what goes in argv[0]

Comment: -1 Um no, the 0th argument will be whatever he sets it to.  Now NORMALLY you expect it to be the name of the program (shells and such set it that way), but that's not what he is doing.